# Want to hold for loop array in an event listener so I can send it as a parameter for a function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, frontend, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to change the background image depending on which symbol is being hovered but when I try to return `changebackground([i])`it always returns an array with length 1 and the number 0.

How can I make it so it returns the number of the symbol that was hovered? for example, If the second symbol is hovered, I want it to return a `checkbackground([1])` to the `function changebackground(logo)`
[Here you can look at the symbols to get an idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDqI2.png).

Below is my code

```
let background = document.getElementById("main_home_container");
let factionlogo = document.getElementsByClassName("home_image");


for (i = 0; i < factionlogo.length; i++) {
  factionlogo[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    changebackground([i])
  });
  factionlogo[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", revertbackground);
}

function changebackground(logo) {
  if(logo == 0) {
    background.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/Img/bg1.png")';
  } else if(logo == 1) {
    background.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/Img/bg2.png")';
  }
  };

function revertbackground() {
  background.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/Img/home.png")';
  };
```

Comment: `changebackground([i])` passes an array with the element `i` at position 0 to the function, change it to `changebackground(i)`

Comment: Not only that, but OP will also run into the trap of closures in for loops: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#creating_closures_in_loops_a_common_mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)